# SQL IF EXISTS overwrite error

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, exists, sql-insert

I'm trying to have a system that checks if it exists, if it does then overwrite if not then insert. I have an error in this code but I cannot see it for the life of me. I've tried this two different ways, neither work.

```
mysqli_query($con,"IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM saves
WHERE name='$_POST[name]') > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE saves SET entity='$_POST[saveEntity]' WHERE name='$_POST[name]'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO saves (`name`, `ID`, `entity`)
    VALUES ('$_POST[name]', NULL, '$_POST[saveEntity]')
END");
```

OR

```
mysqli_query($con,"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM saves WHERE name='$_POST[name]')
BEGIN
    UPDATE saves SET entity='$_POST[saveEntity]' WHERE name='$_POST[name]'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO saves (`name`, `ID`, `entity`)
    VALUES ('$_POST[name]', NULL, '$_POST[saveEntity]')
END");
```

Comment: What [error](http://www.php.net/mysqli_error) message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set primary key on "name" column and then use syntax like:

> INSERT INTO saves (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (1,2,3,...)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entity='your value';

Answer (score 0):

Try this or you might have to adapt the +'"  and '"+ i

```
mysqli_query($con,"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM saves WHERE name='"+$_POST[name]+"')
BEGIN
    UPDATE saves SET entity='"
+ $_POST[saveEntity]+ "'  WHERE name='"+$_POST[name]+"'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO saves (`name`, `ID`, `entity`)
    VALUES ('"+$_POST[name]+"', NULL, '"+$_POST[saveEntity]+"')
END");
```

But for the sql i would just insert where it dose not exist
then up date it all i dont know that is my thought

```
mysqli_query($con,"
INSERT INTO saves (`name`, `ID`, `entity`)
    VALUES ('"+$_POST[name]+"', NULL, '"+$_POST[saveEntity]+"')
where name not in 
(SELECT name FROM saves WHERE name)

go 
    UPDATE saves SET entity='"
+ $_POST[saveEntity]+ "'  WHERE name='"+$_POST[name]+"'");
```

Comment: That's not the issue i have tried replacing all the php with strings and running the code straight through the server and it still returned an error.